# Tumblr Blogs Canonicalisation

Tags: blogs, tumblr, canonicalization

I have created two Tumblr blogs using my account. Say gamesplay.tumblr.com & playgames.tumblr.com. Since I cannot use 301 redirect, Is there a way to implement rel=canonical to merge the two new blogs?

Answer (score 1):

```
{block:PermalinkPage}<link rel='canonical' href='{Permalink}'>{/block:PermalinkPage}
```

Add that into to head of you template